# mpi4py create multiple groups and scatter from each group

Tags: mpi, openmpi, hpc, mpi4py

Say I have a comm for 64 ranks. How can I create a group in mpi4py consisting of the first x ranks, a second group consisting of the remaining 64-x ranks, and comms for each group?

Comment: `MPI_Comm_split()`

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet the arguments for split are 'color' and 'key'. Not sure what those are and how/if they relate to rank?

Comment: what have you tried so far ?

Comment: Unfortunately the `mpi4py` documentation is ... rather sparse .... Just take a look at the standard: https://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-3.1/mpi31-report.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MPI_Comm_split` creates new communicators by splitting a communicator into a group of sub-communicators based on the input values `color` and `key`.

All processes which pass in the same value for `color` are assigned to the same communicator. In your case, the first x processes should pass in a value for color and the rest should choose a different value.

`key` determines the ordering (rank) within each new communicator. The process which passes in the smallest value for key will be rank 0, the next smallest will be rank 1, and so on. If you don't need to change the original order of processes, you can use their rank as the `key`.

Combining these, here is an example in C:

```
int rank, size;
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

int x = 10;
int color = rank < x;

MPI_Comm new_comm;
MPI_Comm_split(MPI_COMM_WORLD, color, rank, &new_comm);
```

Source and further information: http://mpitutorial.com/tutorials/introduction-to-groups-and-communicators/